# Will an ideal bouncing ball ever stop bouncing?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, energy-conservation, collision, projectile, dissipation

By an ideal ball I mean a bouncing point mass with the property that it loses half of the velocity (50%) after each bounce. Now according to my definition of ideal ball, it is impossible for the ball to be at absolute rest once dropped from some height. That is because absolute rest would imply that ball has lost 100% of its velocity after say $N$th (it turns out that this number is infinity) collision which contradicts the definition. But calculating time by summing the time series does tend to a finite value (say 10seconds). Then my question is whether the ball will be at absolute rest after say 15seconds? What am I missing here which is causing contradiction between the answer (10s) and the definition of ideal ball?

Comment: What do you mean by "ideal" if it is loosing energy?

Comment: You might want to read up on [Zeno's paradoxes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zeno%27s_paradoxes) and their resolutions.

Comment: @nasu ideal inelastic collisions, presumably.

Comment: close voters: what's the problem exactly? The question seems clear to me.

Comment: A ball that loses half of its velocity after each bounce seems less than ideal to me! ;-)

Comment: It is unclear in what sense the ball is *ideal*.

Comment: @RogerVadim The OP expressed what they thought *ideal* meant: The ball's post-bounce upward speed is *exactly* half of the ball's pre-bounce downward speed, and this happens on every bounce. No real ball does this. Physicists oftentimes use idealized spherical cows as an approximation of the real physics. This is the bounce of an idealized spherical cow that loses energy only on a bounce, and loses exactly 3/4 of its kinetic energy on each bounce.

Comment: @DavidHammen I would call it an *assumption/approximation* rather than an *idealization*, which is a stronger term. The ball loses energy, so many physicists would readily qualify this as a *non-ideal* situation (contrary to the spherical cow with now friction/losses.)

Comment: @MichaelSeifert When Zeno presented his supposed paradoxes, a good number of Greek philosophers who were present reportedly walked out of the room, thereby disproved his conjectures by example.

Comment: @RogerVadim An *idealization* is any assumption (which might or might not quite be valid) that simplifies a calculation. The OP has idealized the behavior of a bouncing spherical cow. You (and others) are interpreting *ideal* in the restricted sense of an ideally elastic collision. That is but one example of an idealization; truly ideally elastic collisions do not exist in nature.  But it is a good idealization. This hypothetical bounce also is an idealization.

Comment: Instead of word ideal, use absolute. Does a ball comes to absolute rest after it dropped from a height if successive jump of the ball is half of previous. This is debate between pure mathematics and applied mathematics with approximation and limits.

Comment: I've voted to reopen. It is quite clear what this question is asking. The closers are quibbling over the meaning of "ideal".

Comment: Bob D, you had a decisive vote with regard to closure based on your gold medal in [tag:newtonian-mechanics]. This gives you the capability to close a question tagged as such just on your say-so, without concurrence by others. (Normally five close votes are needed. There were only three for this question, including yours.) You need to use this capability very, very carefully. Learn from moderators, who can close any question without any concurrence by others. They oftentimes instead recommend that others vote to close rather than closing the question themselves.

Comment: @DavidHammen the number of votes to close is now 3, not 5.  See [here](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/14133/36194).

Answer (score 11):

> Will an ideal bouncing ball ever stop bouncing?

Denote $t_0$ is the time it takes the ball to go from the first bounce to the next. Because it loses half its velocity with each bounce, each bounce takes half the time than did the previous bounce. Thus the total time spent bouncing is finite, even with an infinite number of bounces:

$$t_{\text{total}} = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{t_0}{2^n} = 2t_0$$

Your perfect ball bounces an infinite number of times in a finite amount of time.

> What am I missing here which is causing contradiction between the answer (10s) and the definition of ideal ball?

There is no contradiction. First off, your idealization violates physics at the sub-Planck level. At some time before hitting the point in time at which bounces become shorter than the Planck length, whether the ball is still bouncing is unmeasurable. Idealizations typically violate physics at some level. The answer is wrong if the violations are severe. If they're negligible, an idealization can still provide a meaningful answer.

The meaningful answer to your question is that after ten seconds (the example in the question), the ball is not bouncing. At some point prior to ten seconds, the ball is observably bouncing. In between those points, who cares? Physicists don't care. Richard Feynman famously disdained philosphy. It's your idealization that results in an infinite number of bounces in a finite amount of time.

Comment: [Relevant wiki link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Supertask)

Comment: Perfect example of why we need to know branch of mathematics called infinite sum convergence. Some sums converges (as this one), some - diverges. Which will be the case- exact form of summation term is needed ;-)

Answer (score 5):

**This is a mathematical idealisation**. You would be correct that halving the bouncing velocity (say, peak velocity) at every bounce will never result in zero velocity mathematically.

**But this is not a working physical idealisation**. In physics, an ideal bouncing ball would lose *no* peak speed (or kinetic energy or bouncing height or whichever parameter it is measured by) per bounce. Otherwise you will have to account for where this lost energy disappears to if you still want it to somewhat resemble reality within the laws of nature. And the very reason that it would disappear might be due to dampening forces which bring us out of the idealisation and thus would eventually result in zero speed. So this seems to be an unrealistic idealisation to make for the a physics scenario in the first place. Rather, a physicist would argue that under ideal circumstances, the ball will forever bounce to the same height without ever slowing down.

Comment: An ideal elastic collision is but one example of an idealization. Physical models oftentimes use idealizations. Despite the fact that a perfectly rigid body cannot exist, physicists and engineers oftentimes assume a rigid body. Idealizations are used in many, many places in physics and engineering.  A ball that loses none of its kinetic energy on each bounce is an idealization, but then again so is a ball that loses exactly 3/4 of its kinetic energy on each bounce.

Comment: @DavidHammen If you idealize to no energy loss, then you are assuming that the loss factors are minimal. If you idealize to a specific factor of energy loss, then you assume away the law of energy conservation. I find these two to be fairly different - the essense is that an idealization is a model and that model ought to still to some degree represent the world it is supposed to exist within. And I found the proposed idealization to be too far off from reality. But it depends on purpose, as I also mentioned, such as whether it is mathematical or physical.

Comment: A purely inelastic collision (e.g., a piece of putty that when dropped sticks to the floor) conserves energy, just not mechanical energy. Some of that mechanical energy is converted to sound, some to heat. Conservation of mechanical energy is an idealization, as is the OP's ball.

Answer (score 2):

There are two ways to look at this problem.

First, lets look at the problem mathematically, The contradiction comes due to the measurement of time. So, how do you measure time in an isolated system ? Because as soon as you bring an observer(clock), you are not in an ideal world. There is no way to measure time except counting the number of times the ball bounces. In a way, in an universe, where this idealisation is real, you would not see the ball stop. But, also, you would realise that total time is finite because time itself would be non-linear and measured by number of times the ball bounces.

Now look at the physical picture. Using coefficient of restitution is a way to model inelastic collision which is a way to account for loss in kinetic energy of ball.
This itself is an non-ideal situation because law of conservation of energy needs to be true. So, you can't see this as an isolated system. The kinetic enegy must have gone somewhere( increse in thermal vibration in molecules of ball and surface). The model works well in classical mechanics when length, time and energy scales are much large compared to atoms where atomic description becomes important. So, invoking the model where ball itself is made of subatomic particles becomes important.

Answer (score 1):

The height of the N-th jump is going down exponentially in N. Very quickly this height will be much smaller that proton radius. The contradiction is that you cannot think of your ball as a continuous elastic object at these lengthscales.